# Assessing agreement

Tags: r, agreement-statistics

Which statistical analysis would you suggest to assess agreement when the scales of the two methods are not identical, but they still measure the same underlying phenomenon?

I'm analyzing a new method to quantify fat on biopsies. There is software that already does that; however I want to know if my new method agrees with the software and if it is as good as the software. I was planning to use Bland Altman but both methods have different scales. Is there another way to test for agreement?

Comment: Can you include a description of what these two measures are? How to express their (dis)similarity depends on that.

Comment: If the scales are different, agreement can’t be assessed, except possibly that the ratio of measurements might be checked for consistency. As @BruceET nicely explains, correlation is more obvious here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is sufficiently vague that I can't be
sure what you're asking. Perhaps you're interested
in something like the distinction between [Pearson and
Spearman correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence).

The variables in vectors `w`, `x`, and `y` are clearly
related. The relationship between w and x is mainly, but
not *perfectly,* linear. The relationship between w and y
is strong, but clearly not linear.

The Pearson correlation (which, roughly speaking, measures
the linear component of correlation) between w and x is
higher than the correlation between w and y. [Computations in R.]

```
w = rnorm(100, 100, 10)
e = rnorm(100)  # noise
x = e + w
y = (x-10)^4
cor(w,x); cor(w,y)  # Pearson correlation is the default
[1] 0.9956207
[1] 0.9638805
```

Spearman correlation is based on ranks. Roughly speaking,
it measures whether one variable increases as the other does.
So Spearman correlation between w and x is the same as between w and y.

```
cor(w,x,meth="spearman")  # Sperman specified
[1] 0.9933873
cor(w,y,meth="spearman")
[1] 0.9933873
```

Here are relevant scatterplots:

[image]

If this is not helpful, please edit your question or
leave a comment to provide additional context, so someone
might give a more helpful answer.